# What do consecutive articles mean?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I [found](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Cold_storage) a sentence:

> The the more common mediums of cold storage are listed with some of their weaknesses.

What does the double "the" mean here? Is this a typo?

Comment: It means you should beware of the the dog.

Comment: Typo. A little research would have helped you here.

Comment: It means despite being a terrific band, [The The](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_The) didn't foresee the downside having a name that doesn't sit well with a world of Internet text searches.

Comment: I still listen to _Soul Mining_ from time to time. Great band.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a mistake. It doesn't mean anything to the sentence.